# How to make an AppleScript app locate itself?

Tags: macos, applescript

I've been messing around with this cool AppleScript scripting language and I have yet another question. How to make an AppleScript app locate itself?
Like something like this (that obviously doesn't work):
`get info of myself
set variable to "location"`
So the output, "variable," would be for instance `/home/Desktop/MyEpicApp.app`.
Is there any script or a sequence of them to get the location of the app and store it in a variable?
Many thanks in advance, even a tiny bit of help is appreciated.

Comment: without testing - & based an only a vague Applescript ken... 'path to myself' or 'POSIX path to myself'. Applescript definitely understands 'me' to mean this script or this compiled app. Never tested how far that stretches.

Comment: Try: `set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)`

Comment: @user3439894 Works perfectly, it's exactly what I want. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the *path* of an AppleScript *script* or *app* to a *variable* use the following *code*:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
```

Example:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
display dialog "The path to me is: " & thePath
```

[image]

If you want the *path* up to the *script* or *app* set to a *variable* use the following *code*:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & ":")
```

Example:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & ":")
display dialog "The path to me is: " & thePath
```

[image]

Comment: one more question: how to remove the slash at the end? what's the "opposite" to "something" & someVariable?

Comment: @Prokop Hanzl, Sorry, didn't see your comment, however I see you got the answer to that question in: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237193/how-to-remove-the-last-character-of-a-string-if-i-know-what-the-character-is-in

Answer (score 0):

To set a variable to the Posix-style path of the current script that you gave as an example:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me) as text
```

Scripts are stored as files, but apps are stored as bundles (better known in the Unix/POSIX world as directories), so the *exact* result depends on whether what's running was saved as a script (.scpt file) or app (.app bundle).

Let's say I'm user "gh" and I keep my scripts in a subdirectory of my home directory named Scripts.

Running in a script saved as foo.scpt, the above statement would set thePath to

```
/Users/gh/Scripts/foo.scpt
```

Running as foo.app, it would set thePath to

```
/User/gh/Scripts/foo.app/
```

Note the trailing slash.

If I want to load a library from the same place as the current script, there are a few ways to get just the needed part of the path, but the easiest is:

```
set my_root to POSIX path of (((path to me) as text) & "::")
set my_lib to load script POSIX file (my_root & "lib.scpt")
```

Whether the script is saved as an .scpt or a .app, my_root always receives

```
/Users/gh/Scripts/
```