# How to remove the last character of a string if I know what the character is in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

So basically I was messing around with AppleScript and created a variable based on the app's path and it always has a forward slash at the end that I don't want. See [my other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237080/how-to-make-an-applescript-app-locate-itself) for more info. Basically thePath is set to `/Applications/MyEpicApp.app/` with that extra `/` I don't want.
What's the "opposite" of `"sometext" & someVariable` in AppleScript?
Many thanks in advance, I appreaciate every piece of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have a portion of the string returned, the format would be:

```
set StringVariable2 to (characters n through n of StringVariable1) as string
```

`n` is the character number of the string starting at 1
`as string` is important or otherwise you get a list of single characters returned

Just make sure that whenever you parse any text, list or other item inside AppleScript to have `text item delimiters` at their default value (an empty list `{}`) unless you want to include those characters in the result as well.

In your example of removing the last character, it would be:

```
set StringVariable2 to (characters 1 through ((length of StringVariable1) - 1) of StringVariable1) as string
```

Comment: @Alex Zavatone, I removed your edit for two reasons... 1. This answer (and question for that matter) really has nothing to do with text item delimiters because by default it's already `{}` or `""`. 2. It was not changed to begin with and therefore no need to do anything with it and totally unnecessary for this answer!

Comment: @user3439894 The answer has everything to do with the answer, because if the user has set different AppleScript text item delimiters then this will not work.  It is `required` to set the item delimiters to what I mentioned or this will fail.  My edit provided a complete solution.  The above failed for me because the text item delimiters were not "".

Comment: @user3439894 The reason I added this in the first place is that the provided solution did not work when I tested it.  This was because I had been using different text item delimiters.  My edits are the result of testing and verification.

Comment: @Alex Zavatone, I must really side with user3439894 as the default is really an empty list and due to the fact, that the answer had been accepted more than 2 years back.  While I agree that changing the text item delimiter may alter the result, it is generally a bad practice to change something and leave it changed for a prolonged time throughout your script and then “complain” that something does not work as advertised.  Therefore, I would rather recommend to change the text item delimiter back as soon as you are finished with it in that section and set it again, if needed again.

Comment: @Phoenix but it is common to change Applescript's text item delimiters and removing the information that I added prevents this from operating as expected if the person has done this, which was exactly my case.  Why remove the information?  It helps in this common use case.

Comment: @Alex Zavatone, while common (I do it myself), it is good practice to put it back to default the moment you are finished with it to prevent unexpected behavior in the rest of the script.  If you need it again, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Phoenix, but many times, such as removing trailing path delimiters from a string, you have to perform this operation while you are using the AppleScript item delimiters for the operation you need the trimmed string for, which is _exactly_ the case I am documenting for.  Also, if the delimiter is anything else but "", it simply won't work.

Comment: @AlexZavatone I have yet to see a case where this does not work.  I have done my share of complex scripts and text item delimiters were never in my way.  At the risk of sounding rude (not intended), but it may need adjusting on your end, if they get in your way.  Again: This answer is a) accepted by the OP and b) is over two years old.

Comment: @Phoenix, I explained it in the edit.  This fails every time that AppleScript's text item delimiters are not "".  The very reason that I posted the edit was that I was getting the resulting string with the text item delimiter added between every character until I set the text item delimiter to "".  I tested this, verified this and added the additional information after validating what caused the problem and what fixed the problem.  That's why I bothered to add the edit in the first place.  If there was no problem, I never would have bothered.

Comment: @AlexZavatone and as user3439894 and I already explained, the default is an empty list.  It is generally bad practice to change it for a prolonged time as this will have negative impact on many things inside AppleScript.  The AppleScript Language Guide explains how text item delimiters work and derived from that anyone can conclude that changing them for a prolonged time will bring unexpected behavior with it.  I kindly ask you to not edit my answer since with good practical use of text item delimiters, it does not add any extra value to this answer.

Comment: I definitely think adding a caveat that text item delimiters must be empty for this to work would improve this answer.

Comment: I can make a small note.  Though, again, I think that anyone using text item delimiters in the first place should really the consequences.

Comment: I hope the edit pleases everyone now.

Comment: @Phoenix, and as I have explained over and over - in *every other case*, it does not work.  It did not work for me.  The code I added _did_ allow it to work.  That is why I added it.  Thank you for the edit.  I clarified what value the default value is, just in case someone changed it and runs into the same problem that I did.  You can't change it back to default if you don't know what the default was, right?  Everyone wins.

Comment: @AlexZavatone I needed to edit your change as the AppleScript Language Guide states “... This property consists  of a list of strings used as delimiters by AppleScript when it coerces a list to text or gets text items from text  strings. ...”, so it cannot be an empty string. AppleScript is, however, a bit blunt and allows you to compare an empty or single-item list with a string without converting one or the other beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This statement uses AppleScript's negative-subscript feature to remove a trailing "/" if present:

```
if the_path ends with "/" then set the_path to text 1 thru -2 of the_path
```

This does nothing (no error is generated) if the_path contains "".